# Error applying IAM policy for service account in Pulumi

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I am trying to create a service account and assign roles, and it fails.

```
p, err := serviceaccount.NewAccount(ctx, "prom-frontend",
        &serviceaccount.AccountArgs{
            AccountId:   pulumi.String("prom-frontend"),
            DisplayName: pulumi.String("prom-frontend"),
            Project:     pulumi.String(c.Project),
        })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // create Project Iam policy binding for the service account to the role roles/storage.admin
    _, err = serviceaccount.NewIAMBinding(ctx, "foo-bar-iam-binding", &serviceaccount.IAMBindingArgs{
        Role: pulumi.String("roles/storage.admin"),
        Members: pulumi.StringArray{
            pulumi.String("serviceAccount:prom-frontend@experiments.iam.gserviceaccount.com"),
        },
        ServiceAccountId: p.Name,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

This is error I am getting from GCP

> Error applying IAM policy for service account 'projects/endor-experiments/serviceAccounts/prom-frontend@xperiments.iam.gserviceaccount.com': Error setting IAM policy for service account 'projects/experiments/serviceAccounts/prom-frontend@experiments.iam.gserviceaccount.com': googleapi: Error 400: Role roles/storage.admin is not supported for this resource., badRequest

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to modify the service account's IAM policy. A service account does not provide cloud storage services, therefore a storage-related IAM role is not supported. That is why you see this error:

```
Role roles/storage.admin is not supported for this resource
```

If your goal is to grant permissions to an IAM member to Cloud Storage, modify the IAM policy of either the project or cloud storage.

A service account is both an identity and a resource.

As an identity, you can grant IAM roles to the service account for resources within a project/folder/organization.

As a resource, you can grant IAM roles to other identities to access the service account (e.g. create tokens).

Comment: I still don't get it. I have a service account that I am creating which is `prom-frontend` 

Is your recommendation to create a new IAM Policy? And attach the IAM policy.

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding foo-bar --member serviceAccount:foo-bar@experiments.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/storage.admin`

How does it work with the above `gcloud` command? I am trying to recreate that. 

Than you!